# How to get full "Media name" from the command line

Tags: disk-utility, diskutil

From the `Disk Utility` GUI I can pick a physical disk and then click info and I get a `Media name` of `ST325062 4NS Media` (this happens to be disk4)

From the command line I can do `diskutil info disk4` and it gives me the `4NS` but not the `ST325062` (or the `Media` but that might not be different between disks).

Can I get the `ST325062` from the command line.  It appears the full model number for the disk is `ST3250624NS` (see attached pic)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diskutil info diskN` gives me the full (according to Disk Utility) name except for the "Media" at the end, so I'm not sure why it's not showing on your system. Try `system_profiler SPStorageDataType` and `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType` (or whatever the drive's interface is -- use `system_profiler -listDataTypes` to get a list). You can also get the relevant info from `ioreg`, but I'm not sure how to find it consistently.

Comment: `system_profiler SPStorageDataType` gave me `Media Name: ST325062 4NS Media`.  I guess, in this case, I have a USB to SATA connector.  Curiously, `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` gives me just the 4NS.